# Converter image WBMP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Boa tarde,

Como converter uma imagem wbmp para png ou jpg usando asp.net core ?
Tentei usar o `ImageSharp`, mas parece que não da suporte a wbmp.

Comment: Apresente o código

Comment: var image = Image.Load(PathFile);

NotSupportedException: Image cannot be loaded. Available decoders:
- BMP : BmpDecoder
- GIF : GifDecoder
- JPEG : JpegDecoder
- PNG : PngDecoder

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta

Comment: Também informe qual biblioteca e versão está utilizando

Comment: Leandro, como já falei acima, tentei usar o ImageSharp, mas ele não da suporte para WBMP, você tem ideia de como faço para converter WBMP para PNG ? eu não tenho código que funcione pois não achei nada que suporta WBMP. Conhece alguma biblioteca que suporte ? consegue me ajudar com isso ?

Comment: Você vai precisar ler os bytes, transformar em um BMP pixel a pixel e depois vai poder converter para png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando a biblioteca "System.Drawing.Common" e com o código abaixo, usando como referência o post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927391/how-to-convert-wbmp-to-png

```
public static bool converter(string fileIn)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileIn))
            {
                return false;
            }
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileIn);
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            int i = 2;
            for (; data[i] >> 7 == 1; i++)
            {
                width = (width << 7) | (data[i] & 0x7F);
            }
            width = (width << 7) | (data[i++] & 0x7F);
            for (; data[i] >> 7 == 1; i++)
            {
                height = (height << 7) | (data[i] & 0x7F);
            }
            height = (height << 7) | (data[i++] & 0x7F);
            int firstPixel = i;
            Bitmap png = new Bitmap(width, height);
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    png.SetPixel(x, y, (((data[firstPixel + (x / 8) + (y * ((width - 1) / 8 + 1))] >> (7 - (x % 8))) & 1) == 1) ? Color.White : Color.Black);
                }
            }
            png.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(fileIn, "png"));

            return true;
        }
```